# Can't resize partition during installation

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7

I want to dual boot windows 7/ubuntu. I have installed gparted, but I can't make a partion because I can't click on the option to resize. How do I work around this?

Also. Tried putting windows 7 disc in, says cannot resize and can only install by deleting ubuntu off it.

Answer (score 8):

In order to resize your partition you'll need to unmount the disk. Though it's likely that your trying to edit the same partition of the drive you booted from. In order to resize that drive you'll need to boot from an Ubuntu live disk and edit the partition from that.

Comment: Live disk of windows 7 or ubuntu?

Comment: And yeah the partion imt rying to create has ubuntu on it

Comment: Be careful I think you cannot resize without formatting the partition while using any of the live CD( Ubuntu or Windows). It is better to have backup of your data since it seems you have only one partition by your  question.

Comment: You can resize without partitioning.

Comment: What is the size of the partition you are trying to resize?

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is the Readers Digest version of what you need to do. Place your Ubuntu Live CD into your DVD drive and boot from it. Once loaded you can now use Gparted to repartition you HD. When using Gparted think ahead as to how much Hd space you are going to devote to it as Windows OS and programs are a bit bloated. Now resize your Linux partion space to make room for Win7. Ok once that is done now go to your future Win7 partition space and make it (primary Partition) Windows doesn't like to share. You can format this as NTFS or not at this point as the Windows install disk will see it and ask you to format it before it starts the installation. Now the last thing you may need to do is edit your Grub bootloader. I have usually done this the other way around using the live CD with Windows as the main Operating system and the Live CD took care of the bootloader for me but would show both Operating systems. BTW here is a web site that someone else went to great lenghts to outline for others (http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/dual-boot-windows-7-ubuntu.html) just copy and paste hope this helps.

Comment: Primary partition doesn't mean primary in that sense. One can have up to 4 primary partitions on each HDD.

It has nothing to do with Windows not liking to share, but more with the fact that Windows needs to be installed on a primary active partition. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 only seems to install if there is nothing else on the hard disk. If it sees grub, it has a hissy fit and refuses to install.

I have created partitions, I have played with cables, and no matter what you do Windows 7 just doesn't install. Older versions of Windows 7 seemed to work, but MS is actively doing everything in its power to prevent dual boot. Not sure if this is intentional, or by accident.

So, safest option is to back stuff up and start with Windows 7 install. Then when that's done install Ubuntu.

I'm sure in the time you have spent on trying to fix this you could have already done it the hard way.

Good luck either way, its a pain for sure, I even contemplated installing Windows XP.

I chose to install VMWare, even runs Open GL to a degree.

Comment: To be clear, even if you manage to create a partition, the install will fail.

Answer (score -1):

I would like to suggest you to use [Gparted Live CD](http://citylan.dl.sourceforge.net/project/gparted/gparted-live-stable/0.14.1-6/gparted-live-0.14.1-6-i486.iso). It will allow you to resize, copy, and move partitions without data loss.

This [tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-gparted-to-resize-your-windows-vista-partition/) will provide you step by step guide. You can also visit [gparted live manual.](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=gparted-live-manual)