# Toshiba Satellite ubuntu wants to use entire disk

Tags: windows-8, gparted, toshiba-satellite

Trying to install Ubuntu on a new Toshiba Satellite Pro C850. When trying to install 12.04.2 but it wants to over write the entire disk . . . ditching Windows 8 completely. Is the only way to dual boot is to use gparted to resize the disk? I don't feel I am experienced enough to try that. Is there an easy way to install Ubuntu on this machine without overwriting Windows 8? Oh I have had no problems installing Ubuntu on other machines.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/263186/cant-resize-partition-during-installation

Comment: Probably not a duplicate as that question mentions Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

> When trying to install 12.04.2 but it wants to over write the entire disk . . . ditching Windows 8 completely.

The installer will only list possible methods of installing.

So ...

- If your whole disc is 1 partition with Windows the installer can -only- erase your current installation. You can create new partitions with the installer but since any alteration is done on the Windows partition this means it will have to be deleted.
- If you have unallocated space it will ask both if to erase Windows or if to use the unallocated space.

> Is the only way to dual boot is to use gparted to resize the disk?

- Yes, if this in your only hard disc. You will have to create a new (unallocated) partition by making the Windows partition smaller.
- No, you could also add another hard disc to your system and use that one.